# Why does a 1D convolution increase the size of the output, while a 2D convolution tends to decrease (such as in a CNN?)

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

The function `np.convolve` is a 1D convolution (e.g. when both inputs are 1D). It results in a larger output size.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> np.convolve(a,b)
array([ 4, 13, 28, 27, 18])
```

However typically in CNNs, each convolution layer reduces the size of the incoming image. What causes this distinction between 2D and 1D convolutions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the documentation of `np.convolve`: "mode{‘full’, ‘valid’, ‘same’}, optional **By default, mode is ‘full’.** This returns the convolution at each point of overlap, **with an output shape of (N+M-1,).** At the end-points of the convolution, the signals do not overlap completely, and boundary effects may be seen."

By contrast, whatever neural network library you're using does not have this behavior as the default.

Comment: Got it! As an addendum to future readers, the behavior is `valid` or `same` in popular library like PyTorch (see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: this is how convolution works. As you can see e.g. in the examples at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution the support of the convolution is larger than that of the convoluted functions:

[image: example of convolution from wikipedia]

As Sycorax mentions, sometimes the tails are omitted for practical reasons. Note that in some application (signal processing comes to my mind) omitting the tails might be an error.